# Operation must use and updatable query. (Error 3073)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

What is wrong with my logic below, is there any alternative to get calculatable column which will sum Balances for every unique KEY ?

Purpose: To create a summary column, calculation of Balances for each unique Key created ( Sort Code + Source Account) which will be used later to define whether acc type is Dr/Cr.

Code: below code should create summary column , but every time it triggers error depicted in attached screenshot.

```
***' Creating Sum of Balances based on Key , to differtiate Dr/Cr Account types
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE Output_File ADD Summing varchar(255)"
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Output_File SET Summing =" _
         & "(SELECT SUM(Output_File.CURR_VALUE)" _
         & " FROM Output_File GROUP BY Output_File.`UNIQUE KEYS`)"***
```

Error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6d1E.png)

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code or error messages.

Comment: For general SQL, your attempted subquery returns more than one row and also you do not use aliases to differentiate inner and outer query. But for specific Access SQL, this will not solve your posted error.

Comment: Also, to save on resources, aggregations and calculations should not be saved in tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access SQL, update queries must be updateable or not read-only. Any use of subqueries renders the query read-only.  See Allen Browne's [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) One workaround is to use domain aggregates such as [**`DSum`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.dsum) available in Access SQL and VBA.

Ideally, too, consider using a saved query and avoid the need of building long SQL statements in VBA and have to worry about line breaks and concatenations. Below assumes `UNIQUE KEYS` is a number field. If text field, wrap in single quotes. If a date field, wrap in hashtags/pound symbols.

**SQL** *(save as stored query)*

```sql
UPDATE Output_File o
SET Summing = DSum("CURR_VALUE", "Output_File", "`UNIQUE KEYS` = " & o.`UNIQUE KEYS`)
```

**VBA** *(reference above saved query)*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedQuery"     ' NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES

CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedQuery"   ' ALTERNATIVE CALL
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, thanks for advise! 
I have used second option, saved query with SQL code as you suggested, but once I'm trying to call that query in VBA  - error appears "query name is not valid...". Any thoughts why is it happening.(I have surfed internet and didn't find any solution to that)

Comment: You need to do both. These are not alternative options but steps in different languages. Save the SQL as a saved query in database and then refer to it in VBA. (In VBA I show alternative calls to do same thing but again don't skip saving the query).